# Serialization and deserialization by dynamic `mediaType` In Retrofit

Tags: retrofit2

```
public interface SthApi {
  @POST("/")
  Call<ApiResult> getSth(@Body ApiReq req, @Header("Content-Type") mediaType);
}
```

I need serialization and deserialization my `ApiReq` and `ApiResult` by dynamic `mediaType`

What should I do?